# Incrementing Number Formula

Tags: education

I am trying to find a formula to express the nth term, the pattern is as follows:

n = 4, 5, 6, 7

its corresponding values are as follows:

6, 10, 15, 21

I know this is not worded very well, if anyone can help it would be most appreciated

Comment: $$
\begin{align} 
x + 3 & = 6 \\
6+4 &=10 \\
10+5 &= 15 \\
15+6 &= 21 \\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Note the seventh term is the sixth term plus six.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern is as follows:
$$a_{n-3}=\dfrac{n(n-1)}{2},a_0=6$$
Or alternately,
$$a_{n-3}=a_{n-4}+(n-3),a_4=6$$

Comment: Thank you, the n(n-1)/2 is what I was looking for. Is there a name for a topic I can look up in order to help figure these out? I would never be able to see it on my own

Comment: @user3371750 I don't know - I just used my logic. :-)

Comment: @user3371750 If this answer is what you needed click the green check mark to select this answer as the correct one, and/or vote it up if you like it.